# How to use Django FileField with dynamic Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filefield

I have a Django model with a Filefield, and a default storage using Amazon S3 bucket (via the excellent [django-storage](http://django-storages.readthedocs.io/)).

My problem is not to upload files to a dynamic folder path (as we see in many other answers). My problem is deeper and twofold:

- Files are already inside an Amazon S3 bucket, and I do not want to download-reupload them (worse: I have only a read-access to them).
- Files are accessible through S3 credentials that could be different from one file to another (that is, files can be located inside different buckets, and access through different credentials). Hence, **my FileField must have a dynamic storage**.

Any idea?

(Djabgo 1.11, Python 3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out it is not so difficult. **But the code below isn't much tested**, and I must warn you to not copy-paste without checking!

I have created a custom `FileField` subclass:

```
class DynamicS3BucketFileField(models.FileField):
    attr_class = S3Boto3StorageFile
    descriptor_class = DynamicS3BucketFileDescriptor

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        return getattr(model_instance, self.attname)
```

Note that the `attr_class` is specifically using the `S3Boto3StorageFile` class (a `File` subclass provided by `django-storages`).

**The `pre_save` overload has only one goal: avoid the internal `file.save` call that would attempt to re-upload the file.**

The magic happens inside the `FileDescriptor` subclass:

```
class DynamicS3BucketFileDescriptor(FileDescriptor):
    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self

        # Copied from FileDescriptor
        if self.field.name in instance.__dict__:
            file = instance.__dict__[self.field.name]
        else:
            instance.refresh_from_db(fields=[self.field.name])
            file = getattr(instance, self.field.name)

        # Make sure to transform storage to a Storage instance.
        if callable(self.field.storage):
            self.field.storage = self.field.storage(instance)

        # The file can be a string here (depending on when/how we access the field).
        if isinstance(file, six.string_types):
            # We instance file following S3Boto3StorageFile constructor.
            file = self.field.attr_class(file, 'rb', self.field.storage)
            # We follow here the way FileDescriptor work (see 'return' finish line).
            instance.__dict__[self.field.name] = file

        # Copied from FileDescriptor. The difference here is that these 3
        # properties are set systematically without conditions.
        file.instance = instance
        file.field = self.field
        file.storage = self.field.storage
        # Added a very handy property to file.
        file.url = self.field.storage.url(file.name)

        return instance.__dict__[self.field.name]
```

The code above takes some internal code of FileDescriptor adapted to my case. Note the `if callable(self.field.storage):`, explained below.

The key line is: `file = self.field.attr_class(file, 'rb', self.field.storage)`, which automatically creates a valid instance of `S3Boto3StorageFile` depending on the content of the current `file` instance (sometimes, it's a file, sometimes it's a simple string, that's part of the FileDescriptor business).

Now, the dynamic part comes quite simply. In fact, when declaring a FileField, you can provide to the `storage` option, a function. Like this:

```
class MyMedia(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'appname'

    mediaset = models.ForeignKey(Mediaset, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='media_files')
    file = DynamicS3BucketFileField(null=True, blank=True, storage=get_fits_file_storage)
```

And the function `get_fits_file_storage` will be called with a single argument: the instance of `MyMedia`. Hence, I can use any property of that object, to return the valid storage. In my case `mediaset`, which contains a key that allow me to retrieve an object containing S3 credentials with which I can build a `S3Boto3Storage` instance (another class provided by `django-storages`).

Specifically:

```
def get_fits_file_storage(instance):
    name = instance.mediaset.archive_storage_name
    return instance.mediaset.archive.bucket_keys.get(name= name).get_storage()
```

Et voilà!

Comment: hey, I have tried this and I keep getting an error of circular import on the last function defined

Comment: Hm... circular import is a python thing, and not specifically related to that problem. Hard to help for me, sorry.

Comment: I tried this snippet but unfortunately the file is only InMemoryFile and is never uploaded to GCS